# Error: Missing template carts/destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this error:

> Missing template carts/destroy, application/destroy with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}.

I have this code in cart_controller:

```
 def destroy
   @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
   @cart.destroy
   session[:cart_id] = nil
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to(store_url, :notice => 'Your cart is
     currently empty') }
     format.xml { head :ok }
   end
 end
```

in app_controller:

```
private
def current_cart
  Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  cart = Cart.create
  session[:cart_id] = cart.id
  cart
end
```

in view:

```
<%= button_to 'Empty cart', @cart, :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %>
```

I have the destroy method to take the action but the above error occurs. Where is the problem?

Comment: Are you having any filters in your controller?

Answer (score 1):

before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :edit, :update,:destroy]

remove the destroy action like:

before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :edit, :update]